# Custom Django Logging Filter for a Particular API

Tags: python, django, python-logging, django-logging

In my app, there is this API named 'UserChangeWorkScheduleViewSet' where its uri is 'host/api/v1/workSchedule' I have been trying to make a custom logging filter that would send me an error log whenever a user causes 400 status code. Below is the UserChangeWorkScheduleViewSet in 'workschedule.py':

```
class UserChangeWorkScheduleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserChangeWorkSchedule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserChangeWorkScheduleSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        UserChangeWorkSchedule.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).update(status=0)

        is_many = isinstance(request.data, list)
        if not is_many:
            request.data['user'] = request.user.id
            return super().create(request)
        else:
            for data in request.data:
                data['user'] = request.user.id

            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                self.perform_create(serializer)
                headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
            else:
                print('UserChangeWorkScheduleViewSet', request.user.id, serializer.errors)
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is my customlog.py:

```
import logging

class UserChangeWorkScheduleViewSet400(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        record.levelname == 400
        record.filename == "workschedule.py"
        return True
```

And here is the logging in the settings

```
from api import customlog

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        },
        'only_400_from_workschedule': {
            '()': customlog.UserChangeWorkScheduleViewSet400
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple_trace': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(filename)s %(funcName)s %(message)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'telegram': {
            'class': 'telegram_handler.TelegramHandler',
            'token': '1489551033:AAHbIvspcVR5zcslrbrJ9qNK2yZ1at0yIMA',
            'chat_id': '-429967971',
            'formatter': 'simple_trace',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['telegram'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I intentionally sent a bad request to raise 400 and the 400 shows up like so:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

However, I still do not receive the Telegram log. The Telegram log is working fine for other errors such as 500 though.

IMPORTANT: This logger must log other 500 error along with the 400 error from workschedule.py. If the setting only logs the workschedule.py's 400, the logging would not be useful.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eedI7.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried authentication_classes?

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#authentication_classes